# How to load django query faster?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a database with around 7000 entries. When I load the page displaying all 7000 entries, the template takes around 7 seconds to load. How can I lower the load time? What are my options? other than caching?

See below the screenshot from network tab in Google Chrome.

[image]

Comment: We can't tell without knowing what your template _does_. Maybe use `select_related`.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement lazy-loading/pagination, i.e, Initially  displaying the first 'n'(say 100) entries. Then on reaching the last entry you can dynamically display the next 'n' entries using JavaScript and Ajax. Otherwise you can use [Django pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/).

Comment: Can you give me a link for the lazy-loading? It seems like what I want.